I send sats to the Bitcoin Core wallet I created some time ago without knowing what I was doing and now facing issues with withdrawal I am clueless
Some time ago, I set up a Bitcoin core wallet and sent funds to that wallet a few times thinking they'll be safely stored. Well, they are, and probably too safely. I have a hard time getting funds out. I can only partially sign PSBT but I have no idea how that works. When I paste the copied PSBT with another wallet I created with Bitcoin Core I don't get any results. Basically, I have no idea what I'm doing.
I hope someone with know-how knowledge will tell by the few screenshots if the sats are forever locked or could still be saved somehow.
I played around with one of the addresses holding a portion of the funds.
disclaimer: I am pretty comfortable posting these images since it's not life-changing amount :) yet







What is your reason for creating Partially SIgned Bitcoin Transactions (PSBT) - for example, do you have a hardware wallet or some kind of airgapped cold wallet?

PSBT is the only option I have with this wallet. I have no idea what I chose when I created it but it was created with Bitcoin core so, it was not imported and also the wallet generates addresses so I assumed it's all good until I recently tried to move sats. Whoopsy :)

I don't have the hardware wallet but I'm building one. Still waiting for some parts. I was searching if an old Android phone can act as a air gaped wallet and there is an option with a blue wallet as Ben showed https://youtu.be/f-8elm8xCLs I tried that too but got confused with which device is my Bitcoin core wallet in his case.

It would be nice feedback if someone could tell if the HW is necessary in my case to retrieve the sats. My mission to build myself a DIY Jade has been aborted due to a lack of experience and knowledge with espressif and I really don't want to throw sats for an electronic HW wallet just to find out later it was not needed for my retrieval mission. thank you
